# Exercise 2, Chapter 4 of Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

> Let $X$ be a Killing field on a Riemannian manifold $M$. Define a mapping $A_X : \mathcal X(M) \to \mathcal X(M)$ by $A_X(Z)=\nabla_Z X$, $Z \in \mathcal X(M)$. Consider the function $f : M \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(q) = \langle X,X \rangle_q$, $q \in M$. Let $p \in M$ be a critical point of $f$ (that is, $df_p=0$). Prove that for any $Z \in \mathcal X(M)$, at $p$, $\langle A_X(Z),A_X(Z) \rangle(p)=\frac 12Z_p(Z\langle X,X\rangle)+\langle R(X,Z)X,Z\rangle$.
>
> *Hint:* Put $S=\frac 12Z_p(Z\langle X,X\rangle)+\langle R(X,Z)X,Z\rangle(p)$. Using the Killing equation $\langle \nabla_Z X,X\rangle+\langle \nabla_X X,Z \rangle=0$, we obtain 
>   $$
> S=\langle \nabla_{[X,Z]}X,Z\rangle-\langle \nabla_X X,\nabla_Z Z \rangle-\langle \nabla_X \nabla_Z X, Z \rangle.
> $$
>   Using the Killing equation again, we obtain
>   \begin{align}
> S&=-\langle \nabla_Z X,\nabla_X Z\rangle + \langle \nabla_Z X, \nabla_Z X \rangle + \langle \nabla_Z X,\nabla_X Z \rangle - \langle \nabla_X X,\nabla_Z Z \rangle \\ 
> &= \langle \nabla_Z X, \nabla_Z X \rangle - \langle \nabla_X X,\nabla_Z Z \rangle.
> \end{align}
>   Because of the Killing equation at $p$, $\nabla_X X(p)=0$, and we conclude the assertion.

How can we get from the first expression of $S$ to the second expression of $S$? 
To answer that question, it suffices to show that
$$
\langle \nabla_{[X,Z]}X,Z\rangle-\langle \nabla_X \nabla_Z X, Z \rangle = -\langle \nabla_Z X,\nabla_X Z\rangle + \langle \nabla_Z X, \nabla_Z X \rangle + \langle \nabla_Z X,\nabla_X Z \rangle. 
$$
So how can we establish this equality?

The only thing I could do so far was that I algebraically rearranged some terms (so that they are all positive) as follows:
\begin{align}
\langle \nabla_{[X,Z]}X,Z\rangle + \langle \nabla_Z X, \nabla_X Z \rangle &= \langle \nabla_X \nabla_Z X, Z \rangle + \langle \nabla_Z X,\nabla_X Z \rangle + \langle \nabla_Z X,\nabla_Z X \rangle \\ 
&= X\langle \nabla_Z X,Z \rangle + \langle \nabla_Z X,\nabla_Z X \rangle
\end{align}
I'm hoping that this is progress.

What can I do now? (Particularly, I have a hard time working with the connection $\nabla_{[X,Z]}X$, with the Lie bracket...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Killing equations is

$$
\langle\nabla_BA,C\rangle+\langle B,\nabla_CA\rangle=0
$$

which gives you

$$
\langle\nabla_{[X,Y]}X,Z\rangle+\langle [X,Y],\nabla_ZX\rangle=0
$$

then you use

$$
[X,Y]=\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX
$$

Comment: Thanks, I kept trying to implement the Killing equation given in the exercise's hint, but that was actually a special case so that did not help. I should have gone back to the original Killing equation which is what you pointed out implicitly in your answer.